Is it true that if a random vector has independent coordinates each bounded by $1$ then $P[ \|X\| \leq \epsilon\sqrt{n}] \leq (C\epsilon)^{n}$?
I'm studying Vershynin's well-written book on "High Dimensional Probability" and the third chapter on concentration of random vectors.
Exercise 3.1.7 from the book is the following.

Let $X = (X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n})$ be a random vector with independent coordinates $X_{j}$ with continuous distributions which are uniformly bounded by one have densities uniformly bounded by one. Then the following small ball inequality holds
$$P[ \|X\| \leq \epsilon\sqrt{n}] \leq (C\epsilon)^{n}$$
for some absolute constant $C$.

I'm not sure if this inequality is true without further assumptions, for example if $X_{j}$ are iid with $E[X_{j}] = 0$ and $E[X_{j}^{2}] = \alpha$ then we have that
$$P[ \|X\| \leq \epsilon\sqrt{n}] = P[\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{j=1} X^{2}_{j} \leq \epsilon^{2}] \to 1$$ as $n \to \infty$ by LLN when $\alpha << \epsilon$?
Also are there any references on these types of inequalities for vectors.

If they are identically distributed and $C$ is allowed to depend on the distribution, then the answer is yes. Otherwise, there are simple counterexamples (basically take each $X_j$ to be almost zero).

You have miscopied the problem.  The exercise requires that their densities are uniformly bounded by $1$.  With this assumption it is not possible for $E[X_j^2]$ to be small, for instance.

Thank you for pointing this out, so if $f(x)$ the density function of $X_{j}$ then $|f(x)|<1$ by assumption, why does imply the second moment of $X_{j}$ can't be small?

For instance $P(X^2 < 1/16) \leq 1/2$ so the second moment is at least 1/32.

Oh I see. You're just integrating out the density function. Thank you sorry for the confusion.

Exactly. (As a hint for the exercise, let $Y = |X|^2$ and bound $P(Y < y) \leq P(e^{-\theta Y} > e^{-\theta y})$ and use Markov's inequality and optimize over $\theta > 0$.)
